# Connecting to X server with xming and putty: 'xterm: Xt error: Can't open display' error troubleshooting

Tags: bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, putty

I keep getting the

```
xterm: Xt error: cannot connect to X server:[:0]
```

error trying to run PGPLOT function. I am running xmings and putty with X11 forwarding enabled.

I have tried echo $DISPLAY and xterm, I did get the same IPs for $DISPLAY but I faced the error:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:[:0].
```

I am using windows 11

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is dedicated to help solve `if/then/else` programming code problems. Please delete here and post to [su]. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do you set DISPLAY locally, and how do you set DISPLAY on the server?

Comment: What is DISPLAY set to on the host where you're getting the Xt error?